# Calculating 50th percentile in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, oop, percentile

I have a table containing 100 thousand rows of the following format:

### UserID  -  Rank  -  Value   - Primary Key

### 1236  -----    00  ----  233.4  --------   1

### 1377  -----    00  ----    150.6 --------    2

### 1287  -----    01  ----   167 ----------      3

### 1343  -----  01   ----   134.5 --------    4

### 1284  -----   01   ----   155.2 --------    5

### 1386  -----    02   ----   302  -----------     6

### 1372  -----    02  ----    108.3     7

I need to compute the 50th percentile, grouped by the Rank, meaning that I need to obtain such results:

### Rank  -----   50th percentile

### 00   ----------    …

### 01   ----------    …

### 02   ----------   …

The 50th percentile of every rank is that row with primary key equals to 0.5 times the count of rows of every rank (i.e, 0.5 times count where rank = 01, 0.5 times count where rank = 02, …etc). However, bear in mind that after I get the 50th percentile of Rank 00, the 50th percentile of Rank 01 will be located at 0.5*(count of rows with rank 01) + (count of rows with rank 00) and so on..

How do I do this in **PostgreSQL**? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use [`percentile_disc()` or `percentile_cont()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select rank, percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by value)
from t
group by rank;
```

This assumes that you actually want the median value for each row.  That is the most sensible interpretation I can make on your question.  Of course, you can change `value` to `id` for the median `id`.

Comment: Hi, I edited the question, could you please recheck the new question and edit the answer? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @EliasMaalouf . . . That is what this query does.